# What will be the path of this particle in combined electric and magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Say a particle is moving with constant velocity along the positive y-axis. Both electric and magnetic fields are applied along the positive x-axis. What will be the path of this particle?

I am confused between these two solutions:

(1) Because the particle is moving along the y-axis and magnetic field is along x-axis, the magnetic force must be directed along the negative z-axis while electric force will be along positive x-axis. The resultant force will be in x-z plane which is perpendicular to the direction of velocity and hence the particle will execute circular motion with constant speed.

(2) The magnetic force will be in negative z-axis and electric force will be along positive x-axis. The magnetic force will make the particle execute circular motion in the y-z plane and the electric force will take the particle in the positive x direction. The combined motion will create a helix.

Comment: Related questions; https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234315/357431 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/758658/357431

Comment: Just write the  differential equations for the vector r and solve it.  If not familiar with differential equation take small time steps,  E only accelerates constant  in x direction, while B  depends on the direction of v and its magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Option 2.  To see this, write down the differential equations for the motion.  We have Newton's Second Law as $m \dot{\vec{v}} = q (\vec{E} + \vec{v} \times \vec{B})$;  assuming that both fields point in the $x$-direction ($\vec{E} = E \hat{\imath}$ and $\vec{B} = B \hat{\imath}$), the components of the Newton's Second Law are
\begin{align}
  m \dot{v}_x &= q E\\
  m \dot{v}_y &= q B v_z \\
  m \dot{v}_z &= - q B v_y
\end{align}
You may or may not be able to solve these equations immediately.  But what we *can* see is that the motion in the $x$-direction is completely independent of the motion in the $yz$-plane;  the equation for $v_x$ doesn't include $v_y$ or $v_z$, and the equations for $v_y$ and $v_z$ don't involve $v_x$.

Moreover, the equation for $v_x$ is just what it would be for a particle in an electric field (without a magnetic field), and the equations for $v_y$ and $v_z$ are just what they would be for a charged particle in a magnetic field (without an electric field.)  So the particle executes uniformly accelerated motion along the $x$-axis, and circular motion parallel to the $yz$-plane.  The result is a helix whose pitch increases along the path of the particle.

<sup>Footnote: This all assumes that the charged particle is non-relativistic.  If the speed of the particle becomes comparable to the speed of light, then the analysis becomes more complicated;  but the basic conclusion, that the path is a helix of increasing pitch, remains essentially the same.</sup>

Comment: Your solution seems right considering the fact that the problem from where I took this case can be solved considering the helical case yet I am not convinced for I am not familiar with the usage of diff. equations in physics. But can you tell me why my first analysis is wrong? Why cannot I take the resultant force and then analyse the situation? Anyways Thank You!!

Comment: @PrasoonJha:  The presence of the electric field means that there will always be a component of the force parallel to the $x$-axis.  So as soon as the particle starts moving in the $x$-direction, the force will no longer be perpendicular to the velocity, and your analysis for Option 1 fails.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that particle as a charge ,force acting on a charge $q$ is

$$ F = q \left( v \times B \right) \tag{1} \label{1} $$

So let say $q$ is along $+y$ axis and $E$ and $B$ (both the fields) along $+x$ axis. Fine use **right hand screw rule** (curl your right hand from direction of $v$ to $B$ and thumb points the direction of force) along $v$ to $B$ (that is $v \times B$) and we see see the thumb point along $- Z$ .

Now we also can see that the **force** is perpendicular to velocity of **particle**.

Power, if you remember is $F \cdot v$ or $F v \cos \left( \theta \right)$. $\theta = 90^{o}$ so power $= 0$ and work also as power = work/time. So, the particle will perform circular motion.

Here's why 2nd case won't happen. The helical motion is when velocity and electric field **makes an acute angle** but our $\theta$ here is $90^{o}$. If it's less than $90$, motion goes helical.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me out. Though I think the solution by @Michael Seifert is correct.